# Firefox 66 - Clear all history is not clearing active logins and shopping carts

Tags: firefox, privacy, history

I noticed that my Amazon shopping cart still had items in it after I cleared all my data (except browsing history) and restarted Firefox later.  Also, when I came here to post this, I was already logged in to the stackoverlow system, and I just had to press a button to add superuser.

Firefox did not used to work this way.  When you deleted everything, everything was deleted.  I have all the boxes checked except for browsing history.  A few versions ago I stopped using an addon that deleted flash cookies, because Firefox said that was necessary anymore, and also the plugin was incompatible with the new version.

After noticing this I went to the CCleaner site, which I used years ago, and the functionality I need is no longer part of their free version.

Any help is appreciated.  Something is very broken.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was that when I upgraded Firefox it cleared all my settings (including in about:config - which is a total pain, but another story.)

The clear history defaults to "last hour" - which is practically invisible the way they have it laid you.  Who would ever use that setting????

I changed the clear history back to my prior settings, and what should be the default: "Time range to clear: Everything."  Now it has this huge warning flag that you will be clearing everything.  The huge warning flag should be shown when you will NOT be clearing everything.

Answer (score 2):

First, Firefox [currently has some issues](https://support.mozilla.org/en-US/kb/add-ons-disabled-or-fail-to-install-firefox?redirectlocale=en-US&redirectslug=add-ons-failing-install-firefox), due to an expired certificate at Mozilla.

Second, *History* in Firefox is a list of sites you've visited. It's not your Amazon Cart.

Finally, Amazon maintains its shopping cart, *not* Firefox, even if Amazon is using cookies to do so. The safe way to delete an item is [click the *Delete* button](https://www.amazon.com/gp/help/customer/display.html?nodeId=468468) or set quantity to zero.

Comment: I am well aware that History is not where my Amazon cart is being set.  That's why I am not clearing my History.   I am not seeing any arnings about expired certificates.  -- My point is, as is seen by my mentioning CCleaner, that I want a program that deletes EVERYTHING (except sites visited history) when I press a button.  If Amazon can do this, who else is saving data about me?

Answer (score 0):

When you clear Firefox's history, you are simply removing all the URLs that you have visited using Firefox. The changes only happen on the client side, your computer.

#### Cookies

On the other hand, Amazon's servers store a record of all the activities you performed on their website. There are millions of shoppers on Amazon every day, so how does Amazon track each individual shopper? When you first visited Amazon's website, it stores a unique identifier, called a *cookie*, on Firefox on your machine. Every time you visit Amazon, Firefox will send the cookie to Amazon, and Amazon can track your previous activities, including adding items to your shopping cart.

You can [remove all the cookies in Firefox to prevent websites from tracking you](https://support.mozilla.org/en-US/kb/clear-cookies-and-site-data-firefox?redirectlocale=en-US&redirectslug=delete-cookies-remove-info-websites-stored).

#### User Session

Did you log in to your Amazon account? If that is the case, all actions you have performed on Amazon is stored and tracked by their servers. Even if you clear all cookies and cache on Firefox, or even use another computer, as long as you log in to your Amazon account, Amazon will show you your previous shopping activities.

In short, items in your shopping cart is tracked and stored by Amazon servers. Any changes in your computer, in Firefox, will have no effect to your shopping cart.

To prevent tracking, you can use [Firefox's Private Browsing](https://www.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/features/private-browsing/) and not log in to Amazon.

Comment: I assume you read my post.  Did you read that I already cleared all cookies?   I assume you read my post.  Did you read that I am aware that the history of sites visited is not related to my problem, so that's the one item I am not deleting?

Comment: I did NOT log back into Amazon when I restated my browser after clearing everything in Firefox other than the sites visited history (including cookies, of course, and existing logins).  --  That's why this is such a serious privacy issue.  If Amazon can do this, who else is storing data about me?    Something is very, very wrong.  I regularly clear all but the sites visited history, and I have never seen anything like this.  Also, like I said, Firefox still had me logged into the stackoverflow sites.  So it's not just Amazon.  There's something wrong with Firefox.